# Zinc Ink Availability

Tags: metallurgy

does anyone know where I could purchase zinc ink? Sigma Aldrich only sell Zinc Oxide, and I'm struggling to find a method in which I could remove the oxide after I print onto a polymer substrate.

Would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: You can buy "liquid zinc" (my literal translation, "Fluessigzink in German"), for repair purposes. Its about 90% metallic zinc powder in some kind of epoxy binder or similar.

Comment: There are many different industrial primers for steel that contain over 90% zinc by weight . Often they are more than one component and some provide zinc powder as a separate addition. Unfortunately they are likely to only be available from industrial suppliers and would not work in a computer printer.